# How to display model data in various formats?

Tags: php, yii

I am changing the data provided by my model in the `afterFind()` method, so the `id` is clickable text, like this:

```
$this->id = CHtml::link($this->id, array('/admin/auditTrail/view', 'id' => $this->id));
```

However, this changes every single occurrence of `id` value - it is in lists, in detail page, even in breadcrumbs, which is unwilling of course. How can I decide which format I will use in different views? For example, in breadcrumbs and in `view.php` I just want the raw value, but in the list (`admin.php`) I would like to use the html link, like this:

```
    'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'html',
    ),
```

On a separate note - is this a good approach in terms of MVC, I mean changing display in a model? Should not be model only used for a database manipulation stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a good approach. There are a number of alternative approaches that would be better, for example:

#### Let the view do the conversion

Don't do anything in the model. When the view wants to display clickable anchors instead of bare ids, it should generate the URLs itself. This is somewhat quick and dirty (it puts the logic of URL generation in the view, which is not ideal) but it's easy and it works well if you only need to do it in one or two places.

#### Expose the URL as a separate property

Place a calculated read-only property in your model:

```
public function getAuditTrailUrl()
{
    return Yii::app()->createUrl('/admin/auditTrail/view',
                                 array('id' => $this->id));
}
```

You can then use the `auditTrailUrl` property in any view. The nice thing about this approach is that the URL generation is opaque to the views and therefore easily modifiable.

You can use this syntax to easily render links from these URLs in your `CDataGrid`:

```
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'class'         => 'CLinkColumn',
        'urlExpression' => '$data->auditTrailUrl',
    )
),
```

In the above definition `$data` refers to each model in the grid, as per the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn#urlExpression-detail).

Comment: I had to add the proper class, like this: `'class' => 'CLinkColumn',`  -does it make sense, is that correct? It was not working, because `Property "TbDataColumn.urlExpression" is not defined.` error.

Comment: @petiar: Yes, it's correct -- forgetting to mention it was my mistake, sorry for that. I have now edited the answer to include it.